# Instagram videos shown upside-down on BlueStacks

Tags: video, bluestacks, instagram

I'm using the latest version of BlueStacks.
I have installed my Instagram account on BlueStacks.
It is for the time that I work on my PC instead of my phone.
All the videos are showing upside-down.

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

the new update is finally here that fixes it, so install it in the about section in settings, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've recenty (today) installed BlueStacks to upload a video to Instagram and the issue persists :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, reinstalling Instagram fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Some people said to try the cog icon in the top-right corner, press Settings, go to Engine, and press "Use advanced graphics engine mode (Beta)".

Note: this does not exist on MSI App Player (Bluestacks 4).